# Function to Make Generic Search in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method in which i can pass a class and pass two parameter Func<> containing my "Where" and "Select" Logic. Idea is to pass class to function give my "Where" and "Select" logic in parameters and use. Here is what I have done so far.

Autocomplete class will get Id and value from my "Select" Func<> which I will provide in parameter

```
public class autocomplete
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Function for Search

```
   public List<autocomplete> Search<T, Tkey, Tkey2>(Func<T, bool> whereby, Func<T, Tkey, Tkey2> selectby) where T : class
        {

                using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
                {
                    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    var query = db.Set<T>().Where(whereby).AsQueryable();
                    var result = query.Select(x => new autocomplete
                    {
                        ID = Tkey,  <----------- Here i want to pass Integer from T class
                        value = Tkey2 <--------- and here string value from T Class
                    }).ToList;
                    return result;
                }

        }
```

this is how I think I would Call it

```
Search<Employee, int, string>(x => x.IsActive == true, x => x.Id, x => x.Name);
```

Problem is I don't understand how would I pass my Id and Name parameter of given class to Generic Search Function.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you ask is what LINQ-to-whatever already does.

Comment: I suspect the real problem has to do with DbContext handling, not generating any kind of generic search - a simple `myContext.SomeStuff.Where().Select(rec=>new AutoComplete(rec.ID,rec.Value)` is more than enough. You could even make that a method in the DbContext itself.

Comment: On the other hand, if you only need to load some lookup values, you don't need an ORM. You could use eg Dapper to run a query and map the results into `AutoComplete` classes directly

Comment: Keep in mind, that you must not use Func<> as parameter if you want to pass it to entity framework. You need Expression<Func<>>. Expressions "describe" the function and can be parsed and translated to SQL by entity framework.

Comment: Stop re-inventing the wheel, use it as it is -> linq does this for you

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static List<T> SearchColumns<T>(this List<T> obj, string searchkey)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchkey))
                {
                    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance);
    
                    if (properties == null)
                        throw new ArgumentException("{typeof(T).Name}' does not implement a public get property named '{key}.");
                    var filteredData = obj.Where(d => properties.Any(p => p.GetValue(d).ToString().Contains(searchkey)));
                    return filteredData.ToList();
                }
                return obj;
            }


Usage : data = data.SearchColumns<T>(searchkey);
```